# Firestore rules - Allow only update certain field of a document

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

**My Goal**

I want to ONLY allow users to update a specific field in the user documents of others.

---

**My user document**

```
/* BEFORE */
{
  id: 'uid1',
  profile: { /* a map of personal info */ },
  connectedUsers: {
    uid2: true,
    uid3: true,
  }
}

/* AFTER */
{
  id: 'uid1',
  profile: { /* a map of personal info */ },
  connectedUsers: {
    uid2: true,
    uid3: true,
    uid4: true, // <--- added.
  }
}
```

---

**The request**

```
const selfUserId = 'uid4';

db.runTransaction(function(transaction) {

    return transaction.update(userDocRef).then(function(userDoc) {

        if (!userDoc.exists) { throw "Document does not exist!"; }

        transaction.update(userDocRef, 'connectedUsers.${selfUserId}', true);
    });
}
```

---

**My understanding of how rules work:**

- `request.resource.dara` is the `entire` target document `after` the change.
- For `update` operation, the above remains true. I don't quite understand what the Docs mean by:

> For update operations that only modify a subset of the document
>   fields, the `request.resource` variable will contain the **pending
>   document state** after the operation.

[ref](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#data_validation)

---

**My rules:** (See update below)

```
function existingData() { return resource.data }
function expectedData() { return request.resource.data }
```

- check if the requester's `uid` is added after the update.

```
function isAddingRequester() {
  return expectedData().connectedUsers[requesterId()] != null
}
```

- check if only `1` or `0` item is added to `connectedUsers` after the update. `0` for if the requester is already in the list.

```
function isAddingOneAtMost() {
  return expectedData().connectedUsers.size() == existingData().connectedUsers.size() + 1
  || expectedData().connectedUsers.size() == existingData().connectedUsers.size()
}
```

- check if all other fields of the user document are not changed after the update.

```
function isNotChangingOtherFields() {
  return expectedData().id == existingData().id
  && expectedData().profile == existingData().profile
}
```

---

**My questions**

- Are my understandings of how Firestore rules work correct? What does the doc referenced above mean by `pending document state`?
- Are my rule implementations reflecting my intentions? I am confused after searching around and learned that the simulator may have bug.
- in my `isNotChangingOtherFields` funciton, am I able to compare the `profile` object directly with the `==` operator?

---

### Update - 2018/01/17 3PM

Removed `existingData()` and `expectedData()`.

```
function isAddingRequester() {
  return request.resource.data.connectedUsers[requesterId()] != null
}

function isAddingOneAtMost() {
  return (request.resource.data.connectedUsers.size() == resource.data.connectedUsers.size() + 1)
  || (request.resource.data.connectedUsers.size() == resource.data.connectedUsers.size()) // NOTE: if the requester is already in the list.
}

function isNotChangingOtherFields() {
  return request.resource.data.profile == resource.data.profile
  && request.resource.data.id == resource.data.id
}

function isNotAddingOtherFields() {
  return request.resource.data.size() == resource.data.size()
}
```

**Debugging results**

Interestingly, the results are **NOT** the same in the simlator and in production.

```
// PASSED in simulator & production:      
allow update: if isAddingRequester();

// PASSED in simulator but NOT production:
allow update: if isNotChangingOtherFields();

// PASSED in simulator but NOT production:
allow update: if isNotAddingOtherFields();

// FAILED in both simulator AND production:
allow update: if isAddingOneAtMost();

// NOTE: inserted 2 mock data before update.
// PASSED in simulator:
allow update: if resource.data.connectedUsers.size() == 2;

// FAILED in simulator:
allow update: if request.resource.data.connectedUsers.size() == 3; 
// PASSED in simulator:
allow update: if request.resource.data.connectedUsers.size() == 1;
```

---

**Question**

If `request.resource` is the document after the update, why is `request.resource.data.connectedUsers.size()` 1 instead of `3` (2 existing + 1 the new added)?

**Related finding (from simulator)**

If I have a function:

```
expectedData() { return request.resource.data }
```

And I got such unexpected results:

```
// PASSED:
allow update: if request.resource.data.id == expectedData().id;

// FAILED if the order is changed.
allow update: if expectedData().id == request.resource.data.id;
```

Comment: Too many questions in one post. "My understanding of how rules work:

request.resource.dara is the entire target document after the change.

For update operation, the above remains true." That is correct. The documentation is saying the same (using "pending" for what you call "after the change"), although I admit it could be clearer.

Comment: What is `expectedData()` in your rules? Also: what is the problem with the code? Is it rejecting a write you want to allow? Or allowing a write you want to reject?

Comment: Have you considered breaking down each bit of the overall rule and test each individually, completely independenty of each other, rather than trying to debug the entire thing at once?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thanks for the explanation. I've added some debugging updates at the bottom of my post.

Comment: @DougStevenson Thanks for the suggestiong, I've did some debugging and updated in my post.

Comment: If you're concerned about the differences between the console simulation and the actual product, you might want to instead start working with the emulator, which lets you run local tests against the actual code that evaluates rules.  This is the preferred way of testing rules going forward (the console is known to be off in some ways).  https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/test-rules-emulator

Comment: comparing maps/arrays with `==` might be causing issues

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It looks like there is a really helpful MapDiff type that might be able to simplify your rules. Sample code from the docs:

```
// Compare two Map objects and return whether the key "a" has been
// affected; that is, key "a" was added or removed, or its value was updated.
request.resource.data.diff(resource.data).affectedKeys().hasOnly(["a"]);
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.MapDiff

Answer (score 0):

In **Firestore**, `request.resource` doesn't represent document after update (well, for **create** it does, since all fields are specified there). It represents incoming data, data you want changed in the document, with maybe some additional fields...

To get the document **after** the fields in question are updated, you **need** to use `getAfter(/databases/$(database)/documents/path-to-doc).data`

So expected data should be changed to:

```
function expectedData(path) {
  return getAfter(/databases/$(database)/documents/$(path));
}
```

`Path` represents *path* which you actually have control over, while `database` variable is defined at the top of the rules by default for the database name...

Comment: `request.resource.data` represents the document *after* a successful write operation. It will contain fields that are present on the existing resource, even if they're missing from the incoming resource.